# Function to add HTML tags depending on string content

Tags: php, foreach

I have tried to create a function to handle text from the database to be publish with automatic formating.

If there is a `\n` : it should be converted to `<p>`...`</p>`

If there is a `-` : it should also add the list tags

My problem is that I cant really figure out how to add the `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags.

```
function nl2p($string){
  $string = explode("\n", $string);
  $paragraphs = '';
  foreach ($string as $line) {
    if (trim($line)) {
      if (substr($line,0,1) == '-'){
        $paragraphs .= '<li>' . substr($line,1) . '</li>'."\r\n";
      } else {
        $paragraphs .= '<p>' . $line . '</p>'."\r\n";
      }
    }
  }
return $paragraphs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable (`$ul` in my example):

```
function nl2p($string){
  $string = explode("\n", $string);
  $paragraphs = '';
  $ul = 0;
  foreach ($string as $line) {
    if (trim($line)) {
      if (substr($line,0,1) == '-'){
        if($ul == 0){
            $paragraphs .= "<ul>\r\n";
            $ul = 1;
        }
        $paragraphs .= '<li>' . substr($line,1) . '</li>'."\r\n";
      } else {
        if($ul == 1){
            $paragraphs .= "</ul>\r\n";
            $ul = 0;
        }
        $paragraphs .= '<p>' . $line . '</p>'."\r\n";
      }
    }
  }
return $paragraphs;
}
```

Comment: @MarSch You’re welcome. See (and use) the edited code, however.

Answer (score 0):

Collect all continuous `<li>` elements with text in a string and then enclose *this* string in a `<ul>` and `</ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for the first character to be a dash and, if the previous line did not start with a dash, add the `<ul>` there. Then wrap the line in `li` tags and the same check at the end - if the next line does not start with a dash, then add an `</ul>`.

Then, as a default action, wrap the line in a paragraph.

```
$string = "this is a string.
New line 1.
New line 2.
- List item
- Another list item
Some more lines of text";

function nl2p($input) {
    $lines = explode("\r\n",$input);
    $return = '';
    foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
        if(strpos($line,'-') === 0) {
            if(array_key_exists($key-1,$lines) AND strpos($lines[$key-1],'-') === FALSE) {
                $return .= '<ul>' . "\r\n";
            }
            $return .= '<li>' . $line . '</li>' . "\r\n";
            if(array_key_exists($key+1,$lines) AND strpos($lines[$key+1],'-') !== 0) {
                $return .= '</ul>' . "\r\n";
            }
            continue;
        }
        $return .= '<p>' . $line . '</p>' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $return;
}
var_dump(nl2p($string));

/*
<p>this is a string.</p>
<p>New line 1.</p>
<p>New line 2.</p>
<ul>
<li>- List item</li>
<li>- Another list item</li>
</ul>
<p>Some more lines of text</p>

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nl2p($input) {
    if(strpos($input, "\n")) {
        $slash = explode("\n",$input);
        $newPara = '';
        foreach($slash as $slashval) {
            $slashval = '@'.$slashval;
            if(strpos($slashval,"-")) {
                $slashval = substr($slashval, 1);
                $hypen = explode("-",$slashval);
                $newPara .= '<ul>';
                foreach($hypen as $hypenval) {
                    if(!empty($hypenval)) {
                        $newPara .= '<li>'.$hypenval.'</li>';
                    }
                }
                $newPara .= '</ul>';
            } else {
                $slashval = substr($slashval, 1);
                $newPara .= '<p>'.$slashval.'</p>';
            }
        }
        return $newPara;
    } else {
        $slashval = $input;
        if(strpos($slashval,"-")) {
            $hypen = explode("-",$slashval);
            $newPara .= '<ul>';
            foreach($hypen as $cnt => $hypenval) {
                if($cnt == 0) {
                    $start = $hypenval;
                } else {
                    if(!empty($hypenval)) {
                        $newPara .= '<li>'.$hypenval.'</li>';
                    }
                }
            }
            $newPara .= '</ul>';
            $newPara = $start.$newPara;
        } else {
            $slashval = '@'.$input;
            if(strpos($slashval,"-")) {
                $slashval = substr($slashval, 1);
                $hypen = explode("-",$slashval);
                $newPara .= '<ul>';
                foreach($hypen as $hypenval) {
                    if(!empty($hypenval)) {
                        $newPara .= '<li>'.$hypenval.'</li>';
                    }
                }
                $newPara .= '</ul>';
            }   
        }
        return $newPara;
    }
    return $input;
}
```